# how to retrieve group list a user is a member or admin in xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework, strophe, muc

I am working on the chat application. I want to implement the group chat functionality in the web client. I have done things till group create and basic configuration and joining the group. I want to know if there is any extension developed Or any other way by which I can get the list of group which user has created or is member of. e.g in watsapp, any body can create group and add me as a member. how to konw which room i have been added as a member, is there any iq request in xmpp muc.

Comment: i have used xep 45 but this query retreives all available chat rooms, but i want specific room which i have created or i am a member of                                                              <iq from='user@localhost.com'
     to='conference.localhost.com'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>

Answer (score 0):

Your iq is close. You need to address the room, not the server.

```
var iq = $iq({
    type: 'get',
    from: 'userjid@jabber.server.com',
    to: 'roomname@conference.jabber.server.com'
    }).c('query', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' });
```

Comment: thanks mark, but my question is suppose somebody has created the group and added me as a member,  and i want to know which room, how can i do this.

Comment: @praveenraj did u find out?